# How can I debug nextjs export

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, static-site

I have a thousand-pages site built with nextjs and mysql. When I generate static pages using the `next export` command I sometimes get the `Hangup` warning. There isn't any useful information about what is going wrong.

Each page requests data from mysql, so there are a lot of request. I suppose it can be a reason of the 'Hangup' warning, but I'm not sure. Requests are quite simple.

It there any way to debug it? Probably the `verbose` flag for the `next export` command or something like this? I've checked the `next export -h`, but found nothing interesting.

Comment: Do you make requests from getInitialProps, or when? Please share the sources of one of your pages please, to see how do you connect to mysql

Comment: 'Do you make requests from getInitialProps' - yes